# Is it possible to use HTML form in Zend Framework instead of ZendForm?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2

Is it possible to use HTML form in Zend Framework instead of ZendForm ? In particular to a phtml file?

If so how is the <form action "abc.php"> going to work when form is submitted. Should I define abc.php in models?

Just a few weeks knowledge only on Zend Framework. Any helpful guidance.

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use html form instead of zend form in phtml files.
In the form tag you can specify the route that you set in module.config.php of your module.

For example if you set this route in the module "user":

```
'route' => '/user[/:action][/:id]'
```

In the phtml file you can add the form tag in this way:

```
<form action="user/add" method="POST">
```

And in the UserController you can retreive data in the addAction.

```
public function addAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $formData = $request->getPost();
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank youu...I have not created any module so I dont see any module.config.php. I simply have index.phtml in view and indexaction in controller and the action in form points to a php file in models where I check the username and password with a hardcoded value. Pls help.

Comment: Ok, if you have not created any module I think you are working in the module Application that is provided by the skeleton. Try to point to application module and index action: <form action="application/index" method="POST"> and check if you can retreive form data from post.

Comment: Requested url not found error...My form is in .phtml file. On form submission it should call indexAction in controller where it will call the php file in models. This is the flow..Any idea ?

Comment: In the Application folder you should have a folder named "config" and inside it a file named "module.config.php". In this file you have router configuration. Could you post this configuration? Because I tried starting with default Laminas skeleton (new name of ZF2 framework) and in IndexAction I correctly receive POST data with this in phtml file: <form action="application/index" method="POST">

Comment: There is no module.config.php in config. There is application.ini